# Matplotlib Concentration plot can not show up [Python 2.7 (with Eclipse) ]

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib, plot, polygon

I would like to ask for help.
Please for help me with my code in Python 2.7. I want plotting concentration of gas release.
Two weeks ago I started with Python, I did not see it before, I have basic knowledge with Pascal, but it is different language.

I do not know why does not work...

This picture showing how it must look like:
flickr.com/photos/95370861@N02/8696658905/in/photostream/lightbox/

My code:

```
from __future__ import division
from matplotlib.patches import Polygon, Rectangle
import math
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def draw(x, y,ax, color, lw=1):

    xr, yr = np.copy(x)[::-1], np.copy(y)[::-1]    
    for i in range(len(y)):
        y[i] = -y[i]
    verts = zip(x.tolist() + xr.tolist(), y.tolist() + yr.tolist())    
    poly = Polygon(verts, facecolor=color, edgecolor='k', lw=lw)
    ax.add_patch(poly)


def concentration_chart_plume(x,y, ax, ticks, colors, title):      

    maxX = 0
    for tick, color in zip(ticks[::-1], colors):
        x, y = calculation(tick)
        draw(np.array(x), np.array(y), ax, color)
        maxX = max([maxX] + x) 

    ''' plot parameters '''
    plt.xlim(0, maxX)
    plt.axis('equal')
    plt.xlabel('$x[m]$')
    plt.ylabel('$y[m]$')
    plt.title(title)
    sqrs = [Rectangle((0, 0), 1, 1, fc=clr) for clr in colors[::-1]]
    desc = ["> %g" % tick for tick in ticks]
    plt.legend(sqrs, desc, title="Concentration $kg/m^3$")
    plt.grid()



def calculation(tick,m):    
    cx = FILE_1
    sy = FILE_2       
    x  = FILE_3
    y  = [sy * np.sqrt(2 * np.log(cx / (tick)))]    #I do not know, how can be limited to non-zero values       
    return (x, y)



if __name__ == "__main__":    
    ''' Concentration plot of continuous gas release '''
    title = u"conturs"
    colors = ["#9EFF00", "#FFF500", "#FF9900", "#FF2E00"]    
    ticks = [0.1, 1e-2, 1e-3, 1e-4]  # value of concentration kg/m3, I want to show up
    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = fig.gca()    
    plt.show()
```

FILE_1 values:

```
[  2.21000000e+00   2.19000000e+00   2.16000000e+00   2.12000000e+00
   2.08000000e+00   1.90000000e+00   1.71000000e+00   1.18000000e+00
   7.93000000e-01   3.55000000e-01   1.93000000e-01   7.02500000e-02
   3.70800000e-02   1.37100000e-02   7.42100000e-03   4.77800000e-03
   3.39200000e-03   2.56200000e-03   2.02100000e-03   1.64600000e-03
   1.37300000e-03   1.16800000e-03   1.00900000e-03   8.82300000e-04
   7.80300000e-04   6.96400000e-04   6.26500000e-04   5.67500000e-04
   5.17200000e-04   4.73800000e-04   4.36200000e-04   4.03200000e-04
   3.74200000e-04   3.48500000e-04   3.25600000e-04   3.05100000e-04
   2.86700000e-04   2.70000000e-04   2.54900000e-04   2.28500000e-04
   2.17000000e-04   1.96700000e-04   1.87700000e-04   1.71600000e-04
   1.64300000e-04   1.51300000e-04   1.45500000e-04   1.34800000e-04
   1.29900000e-04   1.21100000e-04   1.17000000e-04   1.09500000e-04
   1.06000000e-04   9.96600000e-05   9.67000000e-05   9.12100000e-05
   8.86500000e-05   8.38800000e-05   8.16600000e-05   7.74900000e-05
   7.55300000e-05   7.18600000e-05   7.01300000e-05   6.68800000e-05
   6.53500000e-05   6.38700000e-05   6.24500000e-05   6.10800000e-05
   5.97600000e-05   5.84800000e-05   5.72600000e-05   5.60700000e-05
   5.49200000e-05   5.38100000e-05   5.27400000e-05   5.17100000e-05
   5.07000000e-05   4.97300000e-05   4.92400000e-05   4.72200000e-05
   4.35700000e-05   4.19100000e-05   3.88600000e-05   3.74700000e-05
   3.49000000e-05   3.37200000e-05   3.15400000e-05   3.05300000e-05
   2.86500000e-05   2.77800000e-05   2.61500000e-05   2.54000000e-05
   2.39800000e-05   2.33200000e-05   2.20700000e-05   2.14900000e-05
   2.03900000e-05   1.98700000e-05   1.89000000e-05   1.84300000e-05
   1.75600000e-05   1.71500000e-05   1.63700000e-05   1.60000000e-05
   1.53000000e-05   1.49700000e-05   1.43300000e-05   1.40300000e-05
   1.34600000e-05   1.31800000e-05   1.26600000e-05   1.24100000e-05
   1.19400000e-05   1.17100000e-05   1.12700000e-05   1.10600000e-05
   1.06600000e-05   1.04700000e-05   1.01000000e-05   9.92500000e-06
   9.58500000e-06   9.42200000e-06   9.10900000e-06   8.81100000e-06]
```

and FILE_2 values:

```
[  9.21500000e-07   1.68000000e-01   3.13000000e-01   4.47000000e-01
   5.58000000e-01   8.37000000e-01   1.08000000e+00   1.67000000e+00
   2.20000000e+00   3.31000000e+00   4.30000000e+00   6.53000000e+00
   8.50000000e+00   1.29000000e+01   1.68000000e+01   2.03000000e+01
   2.37000000e+01   2.68000000e+01   2.98000000e+01   3.27000000e+01
   3.55000000e+01   3.82000000e+01   4.08000000e+01   4.34000000e+01
   4.59000000e+01   4.83000000e+01   5.07000000e+01   5.31000000e+01
   5.54000000e+01   5.77000000e+01   5.99000000e+01   6.21000000e+01
   6.43000000e+01   6.65000000e+01   6.86000000e+01   7.07000000e+01
   7.28000000e+01   7.49000000e+01   7.69000000e+01   8.09000000e+01
   8.29000000e+01   8.68000000e+01   8.87000000e+01   9.25000000e+01
   9.44000000e+01   9.81000000e+01   9.99000000e+01   1.04000000e+02
   1.05000000e+02   1.09000000e+02   1.11000000e+02   1.14000000e+02
   1.16000000e+02   1.19000000e+02   1.21000000e+02   1.24000000e+02
   1.26000000e+02   1.29000000e+02   1.31000000e+02   1.34000000e+02
   1.36000000e+02   1.39000000e+02   1.41000000e+02   1.44000000e+02
   1.46000000e+02   1.47000000e+02   1.49000000e+02   1.50000000e+02
   1.52000000e+02   1.53000000e+02   1.55000000e+02   1.57000000e+02
   1.58000000e+02   1.60000000e+02   1.61000000e+02   1.63000000e+02
   1.64000000e+02   1.66000000e+02   1.66000000e+02   1.69000000e+02
   1.73000000e+02   1.75000000e+02   1.80000000e+02   1.82000000e+02
   1.87000000e+02   1.89000000e+02   1.93000000e+02   1.96000000e+02
   2.00000000e+02   2.02000000e+02   2.07000000e+02   2.09000000e+02
   2.13000000e+02   2.15000000e+02   2.20000000e+02   2.22000000e+02
   2.26000000e+02   2.28000000e+02   2.33000000e+02   2.35000000e+02
   2.39000000e+02   2.41000000e+02   2.46000000e+02   2.48000000e+02
   2.52000000e+02   2.54000000e+02   2.59000000e+02   2.61000000e+02
   2.65000000e+02   2.67000000e+02   2.72000000e+02   2.74000000e+02
   2.78000000e+02   2.80000000e+02   2.84000000e+02   2.86000000e+02
   2.91000000e+02   2.93000000e+02   2.97000000e+02   2.99000000e+02
   3.03000000e+02   3.06000000e+02   3.10000000e+02   3.14000000e+02]
```

and FILE_3 values:

```
[  2.59000000e+00   2.69000000e+00   2.92000000e+00   3.23000000e+00
   3.54000000e+00   4.48000000e+00   5.41000000e+00   8.00000000e+00
   1.06000000e+01   1.66000000e+01   2.27000000e+01   3.82000000e+01
   5.37000000e+01   9.37000000e+01   1.34000000e+02   1.74000000e+02
   2.14000000e+02   2.54000000e+02   2.94000000e+02   3.34000000e+02
   3.74000000e+02   4.14000000e+02   4.54000000e+02   4.94000000e+02
   5.34000000e+02   5.74000000e+02   6.14000000e+02   6.54000000e+02
   6.94000000e+02   7.34000000e+02   7.74000000e+02   8.14000000e+02
   8.54000000e+02   8.94000000e+02   9.34000000e+02   9.74000000e+02
   1.01400000e+03   1.05400000e+03   1.09400000e+03   1.17400000e+03
   1.21400000e+03   1.29400000e+03   1.33400000e+03   1.41400000e+03
   1.45400000e+03   1.53400000e+03   1.57400000e+03   1.65400000e+03
   1.69400000e+03   1.77400000e+03   1.81400000e+03   1.89400000e+03
   1.93400000e+03   2.01400000e+03   2.05400000e+03   2.13400000e+03
   2.17400000e+03   2.25400000e+03   2.29400000e+03   2.37400000e+03
   2.41400000e+03   2.49400000e+03   2.53400000e+03   2.61400000e+03
   2.65400000e+03   2.69400000e+03   2.73400000e+03   2.77400000e+03
   2.81400000e+03   2.85400000e+03   2.89400000e+03   2.93400000e+03
   2.97400000e+03   3.01400000e+03   3.05400000e+03   3.09400000e+03
   3.13400000e+03   3.17400000e+03   3.19500000e+03   3.25500000e+03
   3.37500000e+03   3.43500000e+03   3.55500000e+03   3.61500000e+03
   3.73500000e+03   3.79500000e+03   3.91500000e+03   3.97500000e+03
   4.09500000e+03   4.15500000e+03   4.27500000e+03   4.33500000e+03
   4.45500000e+03   4.51500000e+03   4.63500000e+03   4.69500000e+03
   4.81500000e+03   4.87500000e+03   4.99500000e+03   5.05500000e+03
   5.17500000e+03   5.23500000e+03   5.35500000e+03   5.41500000e+03
   5.53500000e+03   5.59500000e+03   5.71500000e+03   5.77500000e+03
   5.89500000e+03   5.95500000e+03   6.07500000e+03   6.13500000e+03
   6.25500000e+03   6.31500000e+03   6.43500000e+03   6.49500000e+03
   6.61500000e+03   6.67500000e+03   6.79500000e+03   6.85500000e+03
   6.97500000e+03   7.03500000e+03   7.15500000e+03   7.27500000e+03]
```

Thank you for your help
Prema

Comment: What do you mean it can not show up?  Can you see any plots ever?  Do you see the axes, but no data?

Comment: I can not see any plot...

Comment: Maybe need I change def calculation()?

`def calculation(tick,m):  
  
    cx = FILE_1

    sy = FILE_2  
     
    x  = FILE_3

    while np.log(cx/(tick)) > 0:

         contour=sy * np.sqrt(2*np.log(cx/tick))

         y.append(contour)

    x=x[:len(y)]`

Comment: Usually, if you need to enter a significant amount of code (like your last comment), it's better to just edit your original question, and add it there.  Anyway, hopefully, I've answered your question below.  :)

Comment: If your question has been answered, it's customary to check the answer that worked, and upvote any good answers.  And maybe give a little feedback on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Step 1: Make sure you can actually see a simple plot.

You need to set up python so that the following script shows you something:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x = np.linspace(0,2*np.pi)
y = np.sin(x)
plt.plot(x,y)
plt.show()
```

If this doesn't work, it's no surprise that you're not seeing anything with your more complicated plot.  Getting this working depends on the details of your system, but a good place to start is by figuring out [which backend you want to use.](http://matplotlib.org/faq/usage_faq.html#what-is-a-backend)

For interactive use, most people who need to interact with plots frequently will just use ipython with pylab, started from the command line as

```
ipython --pylab
```

You may need to install ipython and pylab to get this working.

## Step 1b: Save output figure?

Alternatively, if the interactive plot isn't working for you, or you just want to save the figure to a file, you can replace `plt.show()` with

```
    plt.savefig('/path/to/file.png')
```

You can replace `png` with `pdf` or various other file types.

## Step 2: Get your code working.

The code you've posted contains several errors, and no request to draw a plot.  Here are some corrections I see.  Your function definitions have too many variables; they should be

```
def concentration_chart_plume(ax, ticks, colors, title):
```

and

```
def calculation(tick):
```

Your equation should be something like

```
    y  = np.asarray(sy) * np.sqrt(2 * np.log(np.asarray(cx) / (tick)))
```

Python doesn't know how to multiply lists together, so you have to make them into numpy arrays.  Also, you should insert as the second-to-last line of your code (right before `plt.show()`) the line

```
    concentration_chart_plume(ax, ticks, colors, title)
```

which actually draws the plot.

Finally, I assume that you're doing something sensible so that your script gets the right values of `FILE_1`, `FILE_2`, and `FILE_3`.

## Step 3: Check your equation

I don't know what you're trying to plot, but the equation you're using gives invalid values (as you seem to know) any time the element in `cx` is less than 1.0.  Is this really the right equation?  If so, you might want to use something like

```
cx = [max(1.0, c) for c in cx]
```

after you set the values of `cx`, but before you use them.  Then, the logarithm will always be 0.0 or greater, so that the square-root exists.  This basically throws away smaller values of your data, so I'm assuming that they're just noise or something....

## Step N+1: Enjoy the results

After making all of the changes listed in steps 2 and 3 (and correcting the spelling of the title), I get the following very-reasonable-looking plot:

[image: Contour plot]

Comment: Note that I've edited the equation above, because there was an extra pair of brackets around it in the original post.  These cause an error when calling `Polygon`.

Comment: Sure thing.  If this solved your problem, you should mark it as solved by clicking the green check mark at the top of the answer.